# I want to know how to make a makefile for iOS "fat" library

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, makefile

I want to create a (non-xcode) makefile to create a fat library (emulator + device(s)) that can be imported into an XCode project using a makefile that calls the basic command line tools directly (not running XCODE from the command line, but the MAC Gcc and it's related utilities) - this is for .m, .mm, .c, and .cpp source files.

Ideal would be to find an example that works for a simple library (not by calling a makefile generator that makes an almost non human readable makefile)

anyway anyone know of such a thing or appropriate mechanism for doing the same?

Also an ability to extract the complier flags from an XCode project would be real handy :)

The purpose is I want to add a module to my cross platform libraries so I can integrate them into an iOS project.

Thanks!!

Comment: not sure if it helps you but there's supposed to be a cmd line tool called lipo which creates fat libs.

Comment: I found this link when googling LIPO and makefile: http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/resources/Makefile.osx

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the compiler flags by viewing the build details or, more simply, running `xcodebuild` from the command line.

To create a fat binary, you either take advantage of the compiler toolchain's built-in support on the Mac OS X platform by passing multiple -arch arguments, like so:

```
clang -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -framework Foundation simple.m -o simple
```

Alternatively, you build the binary once for each desired architecture, then wrap all those binaries into a single fat binary using `lipo`. This is handy when working with ported Unix software; just change the build result directory each time, then smash them all together after building with `lipo`. Assuming you have `simple-i386` and `simple-x86_64`, you would then do:

```
lipo simple-i386 simple-x86_64 -create -output simple
```

This would create a fat binary named `simple` containing `simple-i386` and `simple-x86_64`.

Comment: this is quite helpful to modify a makefile for different settings, is there an example out there somewhere of a complete makefile that will compile from source, link, and make runnable (via emulator or deploy) a "hello world" without XCode ???

Comment: I can't find the "build details" on xcode 4.0.2 and can't find a reference to it anywhere - only a "log" which has had the detail stripped from it.

Comment: @peterk: Run `xcodebuild` from the commandline and examine the output.

Comment: Thanks - am trying that :)  xcodebuild -project myProject.xcodeproj -alltargets, and I get "code sign error:  The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any certificate/private key pair in the default keychain."  I installed iOS sdk 4.0.x and am able to build the project using xcode.  I assume there is some path/environment issue I need to sus out now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I found this which is a great HOWTO o building a fat library using XCODE that outlines the process and how to create the projects

http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/

being a newbie to XCode and iOS development I had to discover a few things.

- you can view the actual command line output of a build to see what the gcc flags are.
  View->Navigators->Log  - then control click on the messages list to "expand all Transcripts"
  to see what stdout and stderr from the chosen build's build output.
- You can execute an "external build tool" with your .bashrc and .bash_profile environment settings by making the command and arguments a login shell: "bash --login -c 'mybuildtool [my tools args] $(ACTION)', and thus bypass having to deal with the hard to maintain MacOSX launchd settings etc. this works for things like using ruby and rake as well as make etc.